# Additional information: Procedure or function 'spCustomerRegistration' expects parameter '@other', which was not supplied

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to insert data into an MS SQL database table and gets this error when the other field is empty

The Other Column has Allow Nulls set to true

```
Additional information: Procedure or function 'spCustomerRegistration' expects parameter '@other', which was not supplied.
```

Model Code

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spCustomerRegistration", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", txtFirstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", txtLastName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stateid", ddLocation1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@urbanrural", txtStatUR);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cityid", city_id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@areaid", area_id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@streetid", street_id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@townid", town_id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@villageid", village_id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@houseno", txtHouseNo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", Convert.ToDateTime(DOB));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customeremail", txtEmail);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerphone", _phone_number);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", ddGender);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", dal.Encryptdata(txtPassword));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customeripaddress", _cip);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regcode", _regcode);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerguid", _CustomerGuid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@other", txtOthers);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@retval", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters["@retval"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "id");
            cmd.Parameters["@userid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            retval = (int)cmd.Parameters["@retval"].Value;
            pk_uid = (int)cmd.Parameters["@userid"].Value;
            con.Close();
```

Stored Procedure

```
BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON;
            IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CustomerRegistration WHERE CustomerEmail =@customeremail or CustomerPhone=@customerphone )
            BEGIN
INSERT INTO CustomerRegistration (FirstName ,LastName ,StateID, Urban_Rural, CityID, AreaID, StreetID, TownID, VillageID, HouseNo, DOB, CustomerEmail, CustomerPhone, Gender, Password, CustomerIPAddress, RegCode, CustomerGuid, Other ) VALUES (@firstname, @lastname, @stateid, @urbanrural, @cityid, @areaid, @streetid, @townid, @villageid, @houseno, @dob, @customeremail, @customerphone, @gender, @password, @customeripaddress, @regcode, @customerguid, @other )
SELECT @userid = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
SET @retval=1
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
            SET @retval =0
            SET @userid =0
            END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql server does not support null. when any object or value is null then you have to assign value DBNull.Value instead of null.